# Laptop not turning on at all and no charger light

Tags: laptop

Just a couple of minutes ago, my laptop "HP m6 envy 1214tx" suddenly turned off.

When I press the power button on laptop, nothing turns on at all.

When I plug in the charger, I don't see the charging indicator light.

It seems like it is totally dead.

I checked the charger with multimeter and it appears to be working. Is there something I can do?

Comment: Take out the battery and put it back in?

Comment: Tried. I don't even see the charging indicator. Completely dead.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the laptop's charging and power circuit is dead. I'd take it into a repair shop to get them to check out the charging circuit.